# Call script A from script B, and write output of script A to file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh, ksh

I have two scripts, A and B.

I need to capture all the terminal output from script A into a file. I know that I can do this:
`A |tee myfile.log`, or     `A > myfile.log`

However, when I do it from script B, it doesn't work (script A runs fine but output not redirected).

Ex. Script A:

```
echo "I'm script A"
```

Ex. Script B:

```
echo "Starting script B"
A |tee myfile.log
echo "Finished script B"

./B.sh
```

Output:

```
I'm script A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work well enough for me. You need `./` because script 'a' is not in your $PATH. The `./` says 'look in the current directory for my script rather than looking at all the directories specified in $PATH'.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting script B"
./a.sh | tee myfile.log
echo "Finished script B"
```